# Spring Integration Multiple consumers not processing concurrently

Tags: concurrency, spring-integration, spring-jms

I am using Spring Integration with ActiveMQ. I defined a DefaultMessageListenerContainer with maxConcurrentConsumers = 5. It is referenced in a . After an int-xml:validating-filter and an int-xml:unmarshalling-transformer, I defined a queue channel actionInstructionTransformed. And I have got a poller for this queue channel. When I start my application, in the ActiveMQ console, I can see that a connection is created and inside five sessions.

Now, I have got a `@MessageEndpoint` with a method annotated

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "actionInstructionTransformed", poller = @Poller(value = "customPoller")).
```

I have got a log statement at the method entrance. Processing of each message is long (several minutes). In my logs, I can see that `thread-1` starts the processing and then I can only see `thread-1` outputs. Only when `thread-1` has finished processing 1 message, I can see `thread-2` starts processing the next message, etc. I do NOT have any synchronized block inside my class annotated `@MessageEndpoint`. I have not managed to get `thread-1`, `thread-2`, etc process messages concurrently.

Has anybody experienced something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, you say:

> After an int-xml:validating-filter and an int-xml:unmarshalling-transformer, I defined a queue channel actionInstructionTransformed.

Now let's go to the `QueueChannel` and `PollingConsumer` [definitions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#polling-consumer)!

> On the other hand, a channel adapter connected to a channel that implements the org.springframework.messaging.PollableChannel interface (e.g. a QueueChannel) will produce an instance of PollingConsumer.

And pay attention that `@Poller` (`PollerMetadata`) has `taskExecutor` option.

By default the `TaskScedhuler` ask `QueueChannel` for data periodically according to the `trigger` configuration. If that is `PeriodicTrigger` with default options like `fixedRate = false`, the next poll really happens after the previous one. That's why you see only one Thread.

So, try to configure `taskExecutor` and your messages from that queue will go in parallel.

The `concurrency` on the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` does not have effect. Because in the end you place all those messages to the `QueueChannel`. And here a new Threading model starts to work based on the `@Poller` configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I added task-executor="customTaskExecutor" to my int:poller definition and <bean id="customTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    </bean> I now have 5 threads processing concurrently.